# How do i change the format of an SQL output?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.5, and when I am trying to export data from another DB, i use:

```
$fname = DB::connection('smallplanet')->table('pilots')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get(['fname']);
echo $fname;
```

and this is the output:

```
[{"fname":"Aidas1"}]
```

how do i change the output to just "Aidas1"?

Comment: Did the below answer work for you? If yes, you should accept it. If no, you should let us know what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't it be easier to change the source instead of the result ?

For one pilot

```
$pilot = DB::connection('smallplanet')->table('pilots')->find(Auth::user()->id);

if($pilot){
    echo $pilot->fname;
}else{
    echo "pilot not found";
}
```

For many pilots

```
$pilots = DB::connection('smallplanet')->table('pilots')->where('your_field', $value)->get();

foreach($pilots as $pilot){
    echo $pilot->fname . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: No no no no no.. thats not what i want to achieve, i am not making a list, i am making information on the pilot, the name i used is only for an example, i will replace it later with hours, flights, landing rate etc (pilot stuff)

Comment: But... your answer also helped me for making a list, thanks! 

Comment: I'm not sure about the output you need then.

Answer (score 3):

Its JSON ,try this:

```
$output = json_decode($fname,true);

echo $output[0]["fname"];
//********* OR **********
foreach($output as $row)
    echo $row["fname"];
```